# Making the most of available memory on higher end devices?

Tags: java, android

I've noticed that e.g. the Samsung Galaxy S allows apps to allocate much more memory (>24Mb) than a Droid (<=24Mb) or a G1 (<=16Mb) before OutOfMemoryExceptions are thrown. I'd like my app to scale to higher end devices like the Galaxy and take advantage of the higher allocation limit.

Is there a reliable way to detect how much memory my app can use? Is it risky to attempt to use e.g. 70% of the maximum memory reported? Otherwise, I'd need to limit my app to what the G1 allows to guarantee my app won't crash.

Comment: @rebeccaT: "I've noticed that e.g. the Samsung Galaxy S allows apps to allocate much more memory (>24Mb) than a Droid (<=24Mb) or a G1 (<=16Mb) before OutOfMemoryExceptions are thrown." -- is this just through experience, or is that documented somewhere? I would have expected the S to still have a 24MB heap limit, with larger heaps reserved for tablets and such.

Comment: This is why I'm posting my question: newer phones seem to have a much higher allocation limit but I can't find anything in the documentation about how to make the most of this. I'm making an image editor and I can get about 10 800x400 images stored in memory on a Droid and about 30 for the Galaxy. It would be a shame to limit everyone to G1 levels (especially for tablet users). Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()  and .maxMemory() seem to return useful values but I don't know if I can rely on them. Any advice?

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() seems to be very unreliable, after allocating some byte arrays it is even growing for me... but I'm curios if someone has a definitive answer here as well.

Comment: @anselm: I've found (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() + android.os.Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()) a very accurate indicator myself. As soon as this goes over 24Mb on a Droid for example, the app will raise OutOfMemoryException. For your byte arrays, you need to remember that they'll need to be garbage collected first before your reported usage will go down.

Comment: I would like to know how the benefit of knowing there is more space and the changes that result in the program then just programming for the common denominator?

Comment: @kuroutadori: I'm writing an image editor. The bigger the image I can load into memory to be edited (e.g. painted on), the better quality of the final image. I might have e.g. a 800x600 image size limit for a G1 and a 2000x1000 image size limit for a Galaxy Tab tablet. I don't think Tab users would be happy by only supporting the common denominator.

Comment: Use `getprop` for info. I have a high-end Gingerbread phone here and `adb shell getprop dalvik.vm.heapsize` reveals it has 32MB per Dalvik instance.

Comment: @Christopher: getprop doesn't look like an option: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/33e8372ea218ff13 What does Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() + android.os.Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() return?

Comment: Ah sorry, I was just meaning in general to find the heap size of a device; wasn't realising you were talking about direct from code.